# DRF deserializing data from API to django model

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using serializers of django-rest-framework (DRK)

I'm fetch data from an external API, and I want to convert this datas into an internal model (here Period)

The thing is that the field's format of the external api are like this :

```
{"DateFrom": "2020-02-10T00:00:00"}
```

I want to rename into "**date_from**" field.

Here what I tried :

Serializer :

```
class PeriodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date_from = serializers.DateTimeField(write_only=True, source='DateFrom')

    class Meta:
        model = Period
        fields = ('date_from',)
```

Notice that I tried with "`write_only=True, source='DateFrom'`"

And then in my code :

```
json = {"DateFrom": "2020-02-10T00:00:00"}

serializer = PeriodSerializer(data=json)
serializer.is_valid() # This is returning False

print(serializer.errors)
```

And then the output is :

```
{'date_from': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

How handle that ? (in the best way (good practice))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have something backwards here. Given your model and what you expose in your API, you would want to do:

```
class PeriodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    DateFrom = serializers.DateTimeField(write_only=True, source='date_from')
```

`source` specifies the data source on the model, while the name of the serializer field is what the field will be named when serialized.